# Synthesis of a band-pass filter with non-flat frequency response

Tags: circuit-design, passive-filter

I have a non-standard question: I need to synthesize a passive bandpass filter, say \$f_L\$ and \$f_H\$ are respectively its lower and upper limit frequencies but I need a non standard passband response.

I need a [derivative response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiator#Frequency_response) in the sense that the amplitude of the signal between the lower and the upper filter frequency should increase linearly with frequency. I need this kind of behavior in order to equalize the amplitude of a relatively high-frequency sine signal
$$
v(t)=V\sin\omega t, \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
where

- \$ V=(20\div 28)\mathrm{V}\$ and
- \$ \omega = 2 \pi f\$ for \$ f = (2\div 4)\mathrm{MHz}\$.

Formally, the ideal amplitude response should be the following one
$$
|H(j\omega)|=
\begin{cases}
k(\omega-\omega_L) +c_o &2\pi f_L=\omega_L\le\omega \le \omega_H=2\pi f_H\\
0 & (\omega<\omega_L) \vee (\omega_H<\omega)
\end{cases}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where

- \$k=20\mathrm{dB}/\text{decade}\$ and
- \$c_o\$ is some constant.

**The question**

This kind of design is not detailed in standard electronic filter handbooks. I am aware I could use the general Cauer procedure, but I wonder if there are other simpler methods I can use. For example, I vaguely remember an RF differentiator done by modifying a Butterworth filter (however, the colleague that showed me the trick retired long ago, and is not reachable). More directly, *should I use the general Cauer procedure in order to design this non standard filter or there exist other, simpler, design procedures*?

**A bit of context**

The signal \eqref{1} is produced by a power VCO which is fed from a continuous current source \$V_\text{in}\$. It basically consist of a modified Royer converter, which gives an output voltage whose frequency decreases as \$V_\text{in}\$ increases. In my idea, this variable frequency variable amplitude signal is to be fed to the passband block I'm trying to synthesize (the red dashed box in the block schematic below): the output of the block is fed to a feedback loop in order to stabilize the value of a voltage across a load. The whole thing works as a stabilized power supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgzdnZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Notes**

- I cannot use an active filter structure, since the aim of the filter is to "equalize" the amplitude of a power signal: I hope this answers to the concerns arisen by [Kuba](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/10810) and [user_1818839](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/16324) in their comments.
- Regarding the characteristic the bandpass I think the filter should have, as [a concerned citizen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/95619) asked:

  - Require a stopband attenuation greater than \$20\mathrm{dB}\$ seems reasonable.
  - Possibly achieve a transition band width of \$100\mathrm{kHz}\$ may not be impossible.
  - Also I think it can tolerate some ripple, provided the output vs frequency of the filter keep a monotonic behavior. However a Butterworth structure would be preferred, and
    $$
    |H(j\omega_L)|=c_o\simeq 1/3 \iff |H(j\omega_H)|\simeq 1
    $$
    could perhaps be a reasonable set of values for \eqref{2}.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137700/discussion-on-question-by-daniele-tampieri-synthesis-of-a-band-pass-filter-with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My impressions about your requirements are that they are some unfinished thoughts. You say you [cannot use active blocks due to the relatively high voltage and frequency of the input sine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/626672/synthesis-of-a-band-pass-filter-with-non-flat-frequency-response?noredirect=1#comment1656415_626672), yet you are showing the usage of an ["ideal rectifier"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzdnZ.png) straight after the filter. How do you intend to implement that rectifier without the use of active elements? If you're going to use active elements then why not use the same for the filter? What's more, the signal path shows that it goes into an input of the control block -- surely this can't be a current path, which further minimizes the need of using a passive filter. And, if all you want is a device that "*works as a stabilized power supply*", why not use a PLL? That will work a lot better.

At any rate, I'll address your request: how to synthesize a passive bandpass filter with a slope as its passband. Here, too, there are shabby details: you need the corner frequencies at \$f_L=2\;\text{MHz}\$ and at \$f_H=4\;\text{MHz}\$, respectively, with a transition width of \$f_{tw}=100\;\text{kHz}\$ and an attenuation of \$A_s=20\;\text{dB}\$. This, alone, makes your filter order go sky high given that the transition width is very narrow compared to the passband. I've [already shown](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/626672/synthesis-of-a-band-pass-filter-with-non-flat-frequency-response?noredirect=1#comment1656605_626672) that such requirements would need a 12th order 1 dB ripple Chebyshev type I for the lowpass prototype, therefore a 24th order bandpass -- and this without the "differentiator". A Butterworth (which is what you prefer) would require a 25th order (50th bandpass).

Then, you say that the slope-passband should have (proportionally) 1/3 magnitude at \$f_L\$ and 1@\$f_H\$. From 2 MHz until 4 MHz is one octave and it needs to drop (rise) 1/3. [As mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/626672/synthesis-of-a-band-pass-filter-with-non-flat-frequency-response?noredirect=1#comment1656678_626672), -20 dB/dec means -6 dB\oct, or 1/2, so your requirement of 1/3 would mean a -9 dB/dec (got it wrong in the comment), or -30 dB/dec. That's very non-standard since it would require an equivalent fractional slope filter (a so-called ["pink noise" filter](https://www.sound-au.com/project11.htm)), which will require lossy elements (RC, instead of LC). Since you say your voltage levels are high, it should follow that lossless elements are needed.

With the above in mind, making this a *practical* filter would require some sacrifices. First, in the order of the filter, and that comes, mostly, due to the transition width. If it would be allowed to be 500 kHz, then the Butterworth would drop to an 12th order and the Chebyshev to an 8th. It's still large, since the differentiator also needs to be added. So make one more compromise and allow ripple in the stopband, too. Now a Cauer/elliptic filter can be chosen and, with a 0.1 dB ripple (still rather large), the order is 8 (a 0.1 dB ripple Chebyshev would require a 12th order). The problem with even order Cauer filters (considering the lowpass prototype, 8 = 4*2) is that they require coupled inductors so, to avoid that, go for an odd order, while also try to shrink it. So, if you're willing to accept an 800 kHz transition width and 0.1 dB ripple in the passband, you can have a 6th order (LP prototype 3*2) filter. This can be done.

Now, you also need a slope-passband. [@user_1818839](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/626672/synthesis-of-a-band-pass-filter-with-non-flat-frequency-response?noredirect=1#comment1656392_626672) proposed the best solution for this, a differentiator, to which [I added](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/626672/synthesis-of-a-band-pass-filter-with-non-flat-frequency-response?noredirect=1#comment1656432_626672) that a simple highpass can be used as a differentiator as long as the corner frequency is higher than the bandwidth of interest. Since a 6th order Cauer bandpass will be used, the stopband will have a slope of -20 dB/dec, only:
$$
C(s)=\frac{2.3256s^5+75.686s^3+148.84s}{s^6+3.7463s^5+33.742s^4+74.913s^3+269.93s^2+239.77s+512} \tag{A}\label{3}
$$

[image: [2,4] MHz @-20 dB, 6th BP Cauer, 0.1 dB ripple]

The inevitable process of rounding up the order to the nearest integer results in stopband frequencies of [1.56, 5.13] MHz @-20 dB, which means 560 kHz (lower) transition width, an improvement over the 800 MHz imposed.

If a simple highpass were to be added, given that the Cauer has quite sharp corners, the smoothness of a 1st order will affect the relative flatness of the passband, adding a droop. Therefore the corner frequency for the highpass needs to be octaves to a decade higher. But that will mean too much attenuation for the passband or the Cauer. A better choice, at the cost of an extra inductor, is a 2nd order bandpass, so that the higher Q will allow closer positioning to \$f_H\$. For the purpose of exemplification, I've chosen \$f_0^{BP}=10\;\text{Hz},\; Q=1\$. The overall results look like this now:

$$\begin{align}
BP(s)&=\frac{10s}{s^2+10s+100} \tag{B}\label{4} \\
H(s)&=\frac{9.0491s^6+294.5s^4+579.14s^2}{s^8+13.746s^7+171.2s^6+786.96s^5+4393.2s^4+1.043E4s^3+2.9903E4s^2+2.9097E4s+5.12E4} \tag{C}\label{5}
\end{align}$$

[image: powers combined]

Because passive filters are what they are, it's not enough to simply make the Cauer filter (there are tables, if not tools), and then simply add a series LC for the bandpass, or else something like this will come out:

[image: brute force Cauer + bandpass]

Therefore it's \eqref{5} that needs to be synthesized. You can choose whichever method you want: solve for symbolic transfer function then solve the system of polynomials, or use filter synthesis (in this case it might be easier), software optimizer, but the end result is something like this:

[image: final]

I've used equally terminated 50 Ω, and left the MHz scaling for later (it can be done anytime). Obviously, the distant \$f_0^{BP}\$ influences the magnitude of both \$f_L\$ and \$f_H\$, it's unavoidable. You could lower \$f_0^{BP}\$, maybe increase its Q, but don't forget that you asked for a sloped passband, not drooped. Since it all goes into a control block, amplification should not be a problem. In fact, since you say the voltages are high, this attenuation may even come as a benefit.

Comment: Thank you, nice answer. Regarding the ideal diode, it will be a synchronous rectifier: I already designed such things in the form of a synchronous rectifier. It is not truly ideal, but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need something like this?
Note that there is only 7 dB between 1 kHz - 1 MHz.

[image]

[image]

For your convenience, I split the different parts, explaining how I got the final circuit.

- 0. Choose R18-50 Ohm (internal generator impedance) and R15 (should choose perhaps 50 Ohm).
- 1. Network at the left of Vo, which is a "lag" (don't know the exact name) pass filter (high pass filter passing also DC).
- 2. Added network at the right of Vo, not included C15 (low pass filter function, cut high frequencies).
- 3. Added C15 ... (for "better" rejection of high frequencies).
- 4. Added lower network (R-L-C // R15) high-pass filter.
     When adding this network, it did not really change the curve (except at the very low frequencies < 1kHz only).
     This is the reason for the high values of the components (and specially R19 and R20)

Comment: Wow, +1. How did you figured out this kind of network? Did you started from a amplitude behavior and synthesized it by some method?

Comment: It was an "intuitive" task and the use of an interactive simulator as microcap v12. http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip.  You need only some starting "ideas" ... and then "pointing"&"changing" component ... to change it interactively (this simulator do it very simply) "curves" to what you need. I started with "drawing" the curves in the interval needed and then adding the bandpass R-L-C ... Note that the phase is perhaps what you don't want.

Comment: NB: the added "R-L-C bandpass" did not change the curve in the interval 1k-1 Meg because of the "high" input impedance (after Vo) versus the impedance  of R15 which is in parallel.

Comment: Note also that quasi-all resistors of the upper network are the same value, so I had only to change the value of the upper capacitors.

Comment: Did not forget the internal impedance of the generator ... Also, the starting curve is Vo (disconnect the lower network to see it).

Comment: R21 and L1 can be deleted.

Comment: Thank You very much, Antonio. I am really impressed by your semi-empirical solution: however I have not accepted it since the resulting network is dissipative and this could potentially be a problem in my application. All the best.